# EventBus: Two subscribers: No subscribers registered for event class org.greenrobot.eventbus.NoSubscriberEvent

Tags: android, greenrobot-eventbus

AndroidStudio 3.1.2, Gradle 4.5, 
In my `app/build.gradle`:

```
implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
```

Here my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }
 @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    }


@Subscribe
    public void onNotLoginEvent(NotLoginEvent notLoginEvent) {
        // do smth.
    }
```

Activity MainActivity do:

1. Register EventBus because it's need to receive **NotLoginEvent**
2. As result when fire **NotLoginEvent** then method **onNotLoginEvent** must call.

Here another activity **BrandDetailsActivity** :

```
public class BrandDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity  
{
 @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }
  @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onChangeNetworkRequestState(NetworkRequestStateEvent networkRequestStateEvent) {
    }

 @OnClick(R.id.myLoyaltyContainer)
    public void onClickMyLoyaltyContainer() {
                 EventBus.getDefault().post(new NotLoginEvent());
        }
    }
}
```

1. Register `EventBus` because it's need to receive `NetworkRequestStateEvent`
2. As result when fire `NetworkRequestStateEvent` then method `onChangeNetworkRequestState` is success call.
3. Send event `NotLoginEvent`

But `MainActivity` not receive event `NotLoginEvent` and as result not call method `onNotLoginEvent`.

In logcat I get message:

```
 D/EventBus: No subscribers registered for event myporject.event.NotLoginEvent
D/EventBus: No subscribers registered for event class org.greenrobot.eventbus.NoSubscriberEvent
```

If on `BrandDetailsActivity` I create method **test**:

```
@Subscribe
    public void test(NotLoginEvent notLoginEvent) {
}
```

It's success call when fire `NotLoginEvent`.

But I need to call method `onNotLoginEvent()` in `MainActivity` when fire event `NotLoginEvent`.
How I can do this?

Comment: "But MainActivity not receive event NotLoginEvent and as result not call method onNotLoginEvent" -- presumably `MainActivity` was called with `onStop()`, such as when `BrandDetailsActivity` was started.

Comment: So solution is: In "BrandDetailsActivity" in method  "onClickMyLoyaltyContainer" first call "finish()" and then call sticky event - "EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(new NotLoginEvent())". And now it's work.

Comment: You was right. It's because call "MainActivity#onStop()"